# Cloud Run - Not able to create a domain mapping with A-record

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a new project running in Google Cloud Run, but I struggle with the domain mapping. Only CNAME seems to be available, but I need an A-record. Anyone know how to fix this?
[Only CNAME available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXVTs.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Cloud Run domain mapping on a subdomain, you can only add a CNAME.

Create a domain mapping at the root of your domain name (don't add subdomain), you will have a list of A and AAAA record to add to your registrar.